# How can I predict player-to-projectile collisions in Box2D?

Tags: physics, box2d, game-mechanics, movement-prediction

I'm making a real time shooting game with Box2D as the physics engine. The gameplay is mostly about trajectory, like Angry Birds. I want to make a slow motion effect and move camera to the player when he's killed, but the effect should start when the stone is still in the air, before the collision actually happens.

The magnitude of damage is only calculated at collision, based on impulse. Because it's a real-time game, the player must be able to move their character's physics body without lag.

How can I predict their death? Is it even possible? I could raycast, but what if another object moves to block its path?

[image]

Comment: What physics engine are you using? How is it calculating the position of the stone every frame? (You could stack that same calculation a few times more every frame, to check where the stone will be in the future.)

Comment: @Anko Box2d, I can use its raycast to predict trajectory. But something may suddenly show up between the stone and player.

Comment: Are those those blocking items also part of the physics simulation? If so, you could clone the `b2World` and `step` the whole lot a few frames into the future.

Comment: Theoretical note: The future of *non-deterministic* systems is by definition unpredictable. See [Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schroedingers_cat), mentally replacing "cat" with "player character".

Comment: @Anko very interesting idea! I've never tried that. But the player can still move so where he go or how far he go is not predictable. Yet I know the player's move speed so when the stone is close enough, I know it won't miss...

Comment: (1/2) IMO it would be much more interesting if you used a raycast to see if a collision has a decent chance of occurring, then start the camera zoom and slow the game down. For every frame, re-do the ray cast to see if the stone is still on a collision course. If the stone is intercepted, the camera should just zoom back to its normal state, but for every frame the collision is still likely, zoom the camera a little more.

Comment: (2/2) This will kill two birds with one stone (word play not intended): you won't need to do any 'looking into the future', and the players will experience the thrill of near-misses as well as direct (or grazing) hits. In fact, I could argue that your effects will become boring if the player knows that, every time the camera zooms in and the game slows down, he's doomed. He will want to skip the 'animation' immediately and try again. But if there's a chance he can evade the stone, you can bet he will be biting his nails waiting to see the outcome.

Comment: Further to the 'near-misses' concept, there's a chapter in Malcolm Gladwell's book, David and Goliath, that talks about how people feel empowered and exhilarated when they feel they have cheated death. If you can use near-misses in your game, I'll bet it will be a lot more exciting.

Comment: (1/2)@NauticalMile hey, that's a very good idea too!! I'm afraid it may not directly apply to my game because the player is hit too often, so zooming in and slow motion may interrupt the on-going game too much.

Comment: (2/2)@NauticalMile   wait..I think I can grab the speed of the stone and setup a threshold about speed, so if the speed is very high, I know it may cause really high damage and because this doesn't happen very often so I can do the zooming stuff.  Thanks again for this interesting idea :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Why calculate the trajectory for the sounds/slow down effects?

If you split the act of slowing down the camera and playing effects into sections upon approach to your squishy victim then you can essentially play them on condition of their proximity.

[This is a great example that comes to mind. The proximity slow down effects employed in Peggle](https://youtu.be/bE2ZfXqtsWg?t=2m30s)

The ball gets close to the peg and starts slowing down. This is actually based completely off proximity, no trajectory involved. If it gets close enough to the last peg it starts a drum roll and slows the game-play down, if it does not hit the peg and goes out of range you hear "Awww.. :(" and all returns to normal, but if it collides you will get the full fledged Overture and winning screen.

This is a great technique if you approve of making your player go "Holy cow, I nearly got hit!". If you have a start-up sound/effect for a death cam that will play before impact  then simply trigger this when the stone is close enough that even if the player moved at maximum speed in any direction - they have a great change of getting squished.

Say your rock is falling and you want to begin the slow down effect to ~4m away from the player: You start by triggering slow-down, move your camera and start focusing on the player - if the rock is then interrupted by other debris then simply exit the slow down focus and your player continues as normal.

[image]

This is essentially how Peggle handle their slow down effect and trigger the end game music and is perfectly viable for using on your camera/rock/squishy pre-empting death-scene scenario.